# Firestore pagination backward and forward

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The cost of document read in my app is going really high. I'm trying to optimize document reads.

```
enum FetchDirection {
    // Last record date
    case old(date: Date, limit: Int)

    // First record date
    case new(date: Date, limit: Int)

    case initial(limit: Int)
}

func fetchPastWinners(fetchDirection: FetchDirection) -> SignalProducer<[Contest], FetchError> {
    switch fetchDirection {
    case .initial(let limit):
        return Firestore.firestore()
            .collection(Contest.collectionName)
            .limit(to: limit)
            .whereField(Contest.Key.isLive.rawValue, isEqualTo: false)
            .order(by: Contest.Key.endDate.rawValue, descending: true)
            .getDocuments()

    case .old(let date, let limit):
        return Firestore.firestore()
            .collection(Contest.collectionName)
            .limit(to: limit)
            .whereField(Contest.Key.isLive.rawValue, isEqualTo: false)
            .order(by: Contest.Key.endDate.rawValue, descending: true)
            .start(at: [date])
            .getDocuments()
            
    case .new(let date, let limit):
        return Firestore.firestore()
            .collection(Contest.collectionName)
            .limit(to: limit)
            .whereField(Contest.Key.isLive.rawValue, isEqualTo: false)
            .order(by: Contest.Key.endDate.rawValue, descending: true)
            .end(at: [date])
            .getDocuments()
    }
}
```

- .initial loads an initial 25 records
- .old loads past records when user scrolls to the bottom
- .new tries to load new data since last fetch (expected to return empty if there is no new data)

The problem is with `new`. It always returns at least 1 record which is the top record so it creates duplicate record on each refresh instead of returning no result when there is no new data

I have tried the following and both return the first record if there is no new data

```
.end(at: [date])
.end(before: [date])
```

Comment: is this swiftUI?

Comment: @JatinRB why is SwiftUI relevant? I just care about getting the correct result from Firestore

Comment: i don't have knowledge about swiftUI. but where you pass last fetch date in or any parameter where it recognized how many data was recieved and where to start new data fetch.

Comment: I'm not sure this would work but, have you considered using a document as reference instead of date? As mentioned in https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#swift  and further documented in https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query#choosing-endpoints

Comment: I was struggling with using document references, but I may try it again since it's safer to use for edge-cases where 2 records may have the same date

Comment: How about using `start(after:)` instead of `start(at:)` ? Also, if you just want to fetch recently added data, using a snapshot listener might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @ T.Aukar I think there is limit on number of active snapshot listeners. Also not sure how pagination would work with snapshot listeners. I want the user to be able to access all records, but I don't want to fetch all those records by default. Wondering if it's possible to change the `limit` on a snapshot listener without fetching all records again

Comment: Another issue with snapshot listener is they make the app extremely laggy, they execute too much work on the UI thread

Comment: If you're implementing snapshot listeners properly then you should not get any UI lag, regardless of how many you have running concurrently (within reason, of course). They're no different than one-time document gets as far as the UI is concerned. And you can implement pagination with snapshot listeners, they just require some extra steps.

Comment: But I'm a bit confused by your pagination approach here. I assume you have a data set that is in chronological order and you want to load the first 25 initially, the next 25 on scroll down, the next 25 after that on next scroll down, and so on. But then what is the `new` direction supposed to fetch from the database and how is that get triggered by the user?

Comment: And for pagination, you should use the documents themselves as the cursors for piecing your data set into separate pages unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: @bxod `new` is to fetch new records added without refetching the existing records, I'll give snapshot listener another try. Here is the performance issue I'm seeing https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/7957

Comment: @aryaxt are you dispatching the snapshot returns onto a background queue?

Comment: @bxod I found the problem. It was my code :( I was decoding snapshot listener to model objects  on the main thread, I assumed the callback would be on background which was the wrong assumption :facepalm. I'll try snapshots again with the new changes

Comment: How does the user trigger new documents?

Comment: @bxod documents are created by my cloud function